# UICollectionViewCell Flip animation not working

Tags: ios, animation, uicollectionviewcell, flip

am working with [sample code](https://github.com/frogermcs/WaterfallCollectionView)
my requirement is i have to flip selected cell to display some options, for that i have added to views of same size to cell named front view and back view, and used following code, but its not working, please help me how to flip selected cell.

```
    [UIView transitionFromView:(self.isBackVisible) ? self.frontView : self.backView
                    toView:(self.isBackVisible) ? self.backView : self.frontView
                  duration:0.75
                   options:(self.isBackVisible ? UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight : UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft)
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    if (finished) {
                        NSLog(@"done");
                        self.isBackVisible = !self.isBackVisible;
                    }
                }];
```

Comment: if you have find the solution for your problem, then answer your own question. so that others can find the soltion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its because auto layout property in storyboard.